# iOS - Streaming Multitrack Audio

Tags: ios, audio, streaming, avaudioplayer, audio-streaming

I'm building an app in which I need to steam multiple tracks of audio that make up a song. They all need to be synchronized so the song plays back naturally.

I've been able to play back local multitrack audio very well with the solution on this thread: [multi track mp3 playback for iOS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902920/multi-track-mp3-playback-for-ios-application), but it looks like `AVAudioPlayer` isn't able to stream.

I've been looking into working with [DOUAudioStreamer](https://github.com/douban/DOUAudioStreamer) because I've read that it's the best solution for streaming audio on iOS without going pretty low-level, but it seems to lack the equivalent of a `-playAtTime:` method, which is how the tracks were synced up using `AVAudioPlayer.

Does anyone know a workaround for this using `DOUAudioStreamer`, or have any advice on another way I should approach this? Thanks.